# magento 1.6.2 - shopping basket price rule

Tags: magento-1.6

re magento shopping basket price rule - i can set one up on a 1.6 store that works - so i know the 'method' is correct, however on a 1.6.2 store the voucher will not work

i get a message "Voucher code "NOWSAVE20" is not valid. This maybe because it has expired or you have not achieved the minimum spend for this voucher."

the code is being applied to a SKU - in the actions tab - as its needs to be applied to only that sku and not the whole basket contents

as i say - this is working on other stores, so its not the method.

i noticed the release notes on 1.7 mention some cart price rule fixes but does any one have any experiance of a fix, or how to track this issue?

thanks for any help on this

Answer (score 2):

Voucher codes are case sensitive - try nowsave20 instead of NOWSAVE20.